# Statistical difference between two curves

Tags: r, statistics, curve-fitting, hessian-matrix

I have prey consumption data on two species and I am trying to determine the degree to which their functional response curves differ.

Here is a small example of my data (one separate Excel file for each species, the non-native had 6 repetitions for each density instead of 5):

```
library(frair)

specie1 <- structure(list(density = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L), eaten = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 22L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 27L, 
33L, 36L, 28L, 36L, 37L, 33L, 27L, 42L, 42L)), .Names = c("density", 
"eaten"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -55L))

specie2 <- structure(list(density = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 54L, 54L, 
54L, 54L, 54L, 54L), eaten = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
9L, 15L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
18L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 14L, 13L, 0L, 5L, 18L, 0L, 18L, 20L, 15L, 
21L, 5L, 9L, 15L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 31L, 20L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 1L)), .Names = c("density", 
"eaten"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -66L))

specie1_fit <- frair_fit(eaten~density, data=specie1, response='rogersII', start=list(a=1.2, h=0.015), fixed=list(T=24))
specie2_fit <- frair_fit(eaten~density, data=specie2, response='rogersII', start=list(a=1.2, h=0.015), fixed=list(T=24))

frair_compare(specie1_fit, specie2_fit)

#FUNCTIONAL RESPONSE COEFFICIENT TEST

#Response:            rogersII
#Optimised variables: a,h
#Fixed variables:     T

#Original coefficients: 
#                 a       h
#specie1_fit 0.22065 0.48170
#specie2_fit 0.01706 0.54308

#Test: specie1_fit - specie2_fit

#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(z)
#Da  0.20631         NA      NA    NA
#Dh  0.03813         NA      NA    NA
#Warning message:
#In bbmle::mle2(minuslogl = fr_nll_difffunc, start = start, fixed = fixed,  :
#  couldn't invert Hessian
```

Then, I tried different setting different values for "a" and "h" (1.2 and 0.015 were default values) but the same error message came up.

I'm using R v3.4.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp I've updated the data and code.

Comment: I would recommend using `dput` and pasting the result here so that others can easily reproduce your data.

Comment: The title of your question does not describe your problem, or does it!

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp Updated using dput.

Comment: For some information on the warning message, search for `Hessian` on this page: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/frair/versions/0.5/topics/frair_fit

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp Thanks for the link. I've already tried some of those recommendations, like trying different starting values but still get a warning. Is there any other way to compare the two curves?